# Multi linked server query

Tags: sql, linked-server, foxpro

I have a Foxpro database that I must query from a 64 bit SQL server. I can't link it directly, so I installed a 32 bit SQL server and linked Foxpro correctly. Then I linked the 64 bit server with the 32 bit SQL server.

Now, how can I query the linked 32 bit server from the 64 bit SQL server?

Comment: So you can't get a 64 bit Foxpro driver? Do you need to query the Foxpro data in real time using a linked server? Or can you just schedule a frequent dataload into a staging table in SQL Server (using 32 bit SSIS)? This will make it way easier and more reliable to query, the data just won't as up to date.

Comment: I know ther isn't a 64 bit Foxpro driver. I must query the server Real Time but your second solution could be acceptable for a "end day" statistics.

Comment: I don't really recommend doing it but you could define your linked server on your 32 bit server, create a view around it, then reference that view from your 64 bit server via a linked server

Comment: Thank you for information. I follow this solution but the performance are not so good :) Other chance?

Comment: Not only is the performance bad, it will be unreliable. There's no other way I'm aware of for adhoc queries. You need to consider whether these really need to be adhoc or whether you can replication the FoxPro data into SQL Server on a regular basis (i.e. every 10 minutes)